# How to find the newest mathematics journals promoted from ESCI to SCI-Expanded list?

Tags: mathematics, journals, indexing

ESCI indexed journals which maintain qualtity publications are migrated to the SCi-Expanded list. Where and how can I find the new mathematics journals that have been promoted to the SCI-Expanded list recently ?

Furthermore, how can I know if a particular mathematics journal will be promoted to the SCI-expanded list soon from ESCI indexing ?